# How to resolve "No plugin found for prefix 'surefire_report' in the current project and in the plugin groups"

Tags: maven, selenium, pom.xml

I am new to maven and I am automating a website. While executing my test cases, I am getting an error as "No plugin found for prefix 'surefire_report' in the current project and in the plugin groups". Below is the screenshot of my pom file
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two different plugins; [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html) is meant to drive the test phase, and should be defined as:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

[maven-surefire-report-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html) generates the surefire reports as part of the site generation, parsing the TEST-*.xml test results, and should be like:

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

Comment: @GUIDO thank you for the response. I tried but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you update the question with what you changed and how you run the maven execution?